# What type of mount is this?

Tags: lens, fujifilm, equipment-identification

I bought this lens - on it it says:

FUJINON-TV Z
1:1.9/10-140
FUJI PHOTO OPTICAL CO.

I am trying to identify the mount and see if I could mount it on any camera system I have (Olympus Pen F, Sony NEX, Beaulieu 16mm, etc)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess the lens says "1:1.9" not "1:19" I guess it's a 10-140mm zoom lens for a video camera - image circle probably very small. But I really am not familiar with such lenses. I would have verified first before buying.

Comment: @osullic - thanks, yes of course - I will correct the typo. It was $10 so even as a bookshelf display it's a bargain.

Comment: 1/2" or 1/3" Bayonet? Mainly uses for video (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_mount#List_of_lens_mounts) for some dimensions that you can check).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is a B4 mount based on the lens appearing to be for broadcast television.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B4-mount

The standard  is intended to cover a 2/3” sensor in broadcast cameras and broadcast  cameras with 2/3”  format sensors are still manufactured today for commercial use, including 4K models.

Ease of achieving useful depth of field at close focus using wide apertures is an advantage of the relatively small sensor (in comparison to contemporary stills camera sizes) for situations like an on location indoors interview.

Another advantage is the small size of the lens relative to an equivalent “full frame” means less high quality glass needs to be incorporated into the optical path and there’s less glass for the zoom motor to move (and less moving mass to stop).

But this also means that the lens will almost certainly vignette on a 4/3” or larger sensor…I say “almost certainly” because I have not tested one and because lenses often have larger image circles than the theoretical design  minimums.

However, Fotodiox currently (August, 2022) has B4 adapters for sale on its US website including e-mount and MFT).

Whether the adapted lens would meet your expectations is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a B4 mount used by older broadcast lenses.

If so, the lens is designed to cast an 11mm image circle, which is considerably smaller than needed to cover the entire sensor of any of the systems you've listed as possible adapted use cases.

Comment: Thanks! But I might be able to put it on my Pentax Auto 110 or Pentax Q 